# Any assistance for specific method calling using Driver class? (Palindrome)

Tags: java

Alright, so Im new to using a driver to call methods, and so far this is what ive come up with:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String s)
 {
  int begin = 0;
  int end = s.length() - 1;
  while (begin < end)
  {
   if (s.charAt(begin) != s.charAt(end))
   {
    return false;
   }
   begin++;
   end--;
  }
  return true; 
 }
```

How do I get my driver to print out true when they detect the String "Racecar".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing can be done like:

```
class Palindrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Palindrome test1 = new Palindrome();
        String str = "Racecar";
        System.out.println("result: " + test1.isPalindrome(str.toLowerCase()));
    }

    public boolean isPalindrome(String s)
     {
        int begin = 0;
        int end = s.length() - 1;
        while (begin < end)
        {
         if (s.charAt(begin) != s.charAt(end))
         {
            return false;
         }
         begin++;
         end--;
        }
        return true; 
     }
}
```

**Output**:

```
result: true
```